# Marveled v. Marveled at

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality

Which is correct?

1. They marveled the effigy.

OR

2. They marveled at the effigy.

Please provide an explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*They marveled at the effigy* is correct. "Marvel" is an intransitive verb—it doesn't take a direct object. So anything in the sentence that receives the activity of marveling will be in a prepositional phrase.

A less technical way to think of it: The act of marveling doesn't affect the effigy, and the preposition *at* conveys that. The preposition creates some distance between the effigy and the action. If *marvel* were like *shove* or *burn*, and the effigy were changed by the action of marvelling, then *They marvel the effigy* would make sense.